# Google Sheets - How to highlight cells in a row that match values from other cells?

Tags: google-sheets

- I have a row of values (say 1-10)
- At the beginning of the rows I have 2 numbers generated from dates from other cells that represent week numbers. (eg, 3 and 9)
- I want my row to highlight all the numbers from 1-10 that are between the values from the week number cells. (eg the cells with numbers 3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9 will automatically turn a colour (say green))

I've tried the conditional format, using the "between" values.
It doesn't work.

If I just type the numbers into the format box, it will work, but the problem is I need it to refer to the value in the cell NOT a number I type in, because there is a likelihood that the dates could change, which will affect the value shown in week number cell, so I need it to work automatically and not require me to go through every single row changing values for the formatting.

Is this even possible on sheets?

Thanks in advance, I am hoping I've just overlooked something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom function for conditional formatting. For instance, if the columns you describe are in Row 2, this function will evaluate "TRUE" for numbers that are `>= A2` and `<= B2`:

```
=AND(C2>=$A2,C2<=$B2)
```

Select the range of cells you wish to create a conditional format for; `C2..L2`, say. Open the conditional formatting dialog, and choose "Custom formula". Enter the formula above; note that itr refers to the top-left corner of the range you wish to apply the formula to - Sheets will automatically adjust it for the rest of the range, which is why it's important to use absolute references for the first two columns.

[image: screenshot]