# Highlight entries in a row that do not match (with multiple instances)

Tags: google-sheets, highlight, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a highlight in my sheet that will allow me on a row by row basis to highlight the version numbers that do not match the master column. I also want the rule to ignore anything that is marked as N/A as it should not be considered.

e.g. column E houses the latest version v1.0.2, columns H-O list the versions available at various locations, two of them are still on v1.0.0. I want any that do not match the master version (outdated) to highlight.

How can I do this and have it apply to each row individually? So row 7 values are highlighted based on E7 but row 8 values are highlighted based on E8. These are not plain numerical values but include text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sheets - How to highlight cells in a row that match values from other cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783150/google-sheets-how-to-highlight-cells-in-a-row-that-match-values-from-other-cel)

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured it out after a bit of messing around based on answers to similar questions. All using Conditional Formatting.

Make sure that each rule created has the correct range applied so only that section of the sheet is checked (in my case H6:O18).

This ensures that whatever rule I add, it only applies to that part of my sheet.

1. Custom formula "**=$H6:$O6<>$E6**"

To explain this, it looks at the range of data entries (From the H to O columns - starting with row 6) and compares it to (in my case) the master entry in column E to compare. Basically asking do the entries differ?

The $ symbols are included in front of the column values to mark them as unchanging. The row numbers do not have the $ symbol and so can change. Therefore it checks H6:O6 against E6, but will check H12:O12 against E12. Maintaining the column but not the row.

2. Additional rule added **"Cell is empty"**

This is set to not highlight - applied to the same range (H6:O18). This is placed above the previous rule to overrule it. Therefore any blank cells are not highlighted as different, they are ignored.

3. Additional rule: **"Text is Exactly"**

This is applied to the same range and ordered above the original rule to again overrule it. The text to check is "N/A". Again this is set to not highlight or alter anything. This ensures that entries marked N/A are ignored much like blank cells.

An extra addition I included was duplicating the first formula but changing the <> to = and changing the highlight to green. This highlights anything that matches while any differences are highlighted red. N/A or blank cells are ignored.

[Example of highlighted cells + Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc7Di.png)